# What is the correct imperative form of "wiederholen"?

Tags: verb, imperative

I would like to say *repeat frequently!* by using the verb *wiederholen* and the adjective *regelmäßig*.

Which one of these is the correct for *du* and which one for *ihr*?

> **du** wiederhole; wiederhol; hole wieder; hol wieder
>   **ihr** wiederholt; holt wieder

Comment: I think your actual question is if "wiederholen" is separable or not. There are a couple of questions here on that site that cover that topic. In this case, it's not separable. And here's the conjugation: http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:wiederholen#Imperativ

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can easily be answered by consulting a dictionary.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: but the dictionary won't tell you about the usage of *Wiederhol!* vs. *Wiederhole!*...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different words that share the spelling *wiederholen.*
In other words, they are homographs. When spoken, the meanings may be distinguished by different pronunciations.

> **wi̲e̲derholen** *(fetch or get back)*
>   ich hole wieder
>   du holst wieder; *imperative:* hol wieder! *or* hole wieder!
>   er/sie/es holt wieder
>   wir holen wieder
>   ihr holt wieder
>   sie holen wieder

> **wiederho̲len** *(repeat)*
>   ich wiederhole
>   du wiederholst; *imperative:* wiederhol! *or* wiederhole!
>   er/sie/es wiederholt
>   wir wiederholen
>   ihr wiederholt
>   sie wiederholen

Comment: Some further discussion can be found [here](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~deutsch/Grammatik/Wortbildung/Inseparables.html#Either): There are several prefixes that are sometimes separable and sometimes inseparable: "through-" , "over-" , "around-" , "under-" , "full-" , "again-" . While not always predictable, it is generally true that when these prefixes are inseparable, their meaning is more likely - but only more likely - to be both transitive and figurative (As a comparison, note the distinction in English between "stepping over the line" and "overstepping the line.").

Answer (score -1):

*Wiederhol!* I believe is the answer.

*Wiederholen Sie bitte die folgenden Sätzte* would be the polite form that I learned in college.